# how to fix "cannot open shared object file" in Cshell script?

Tags: linux, shell, shared-libraries

I am working on Linux system and have a Fortran executable e.g. a.exe successfully run by directly execute. I want to execute this a.exe inside a Cshell script, but is always report error as "error while loading shared libraries: libnetcdff.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

when I do 'ldd a.exe', it report me some dependency of libraries for this executables.

libnetcdff.so.6 => /met5/ZR_LOCAL_LIBS/lib/libnetcdff.so.6 (0x00002ab536656000)

The library did existed, and I also have the path set as $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

the a.exe need two inputs $INFILE1, $INFILE2 and will generate the output at $OUTPUT

it can be executed by hand typing ./a.exe and providing the path of $INFILE1 and $INFILE2, however, when I write a simple Cshell script as the form:

```
#!/bin/csh
#
setenv BASE $PWD
setenv PROGNAME a.exe

cd $BASE

setenv INFILE1 $BASE/agtsc_ave_2017.nc
setenv INFILE2 $BASE/agtsc_ave_2029.nc
setenv OUTFILE $BASE/emis_pct_2029_relative_to_2017.nc

if ( -e $OUTFILE ) rm -f $OUTFILE
$BASE/$PROGNAME
```

it will report the error as:
a.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libnetcdff.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have no idea how to debug through this. Can anyone help me to fix it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. I use other people's .cshrc, so there is a $path issue causing the shell script can not find the corresponding libraries. I delete the older .cshrc file and create a new one based on my condition, the problem is gone. Thanks.